# Can I mention the completion of online courses as professional qualifications when applying to university?

Tags: application, online-learning

I am applying now to a postgraduate program in Computer Science. In the application, there is a subsection where I can mention my professional qualifications; I am wondering if it is appropriate to mention the completion of a web-development online course (on Udemy) with uploading the certificate of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the courses are relevant to your proposed research area, then yes. I did ([after consulting with SE experts](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61176/mention-moocs-in-email-to-potential-phd-supervisor)), was accepted.